# workaround for firefox bug on focus/blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, onblur, onfocus

I have written the following code to check if the value inserted in a input field already exists in the database.

```
$('#nome_field').blur(function(){
        var field_name=$('#nome_field').val();
        $.ajax({
          url: "check_field_unique.php",
          method: 'post',
          data: {field_name:field_name},
          dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data){
            if(data.status==500){
              //esiste un altro campo con lo stesso nome
              bootbox.alert({
                message: data.message, 
                size: 'small',
                backdrop: true,
                callback: function(){
                    //$('#nome_field').val('');
                    $('#nome_field').focus();           
                }
              });
            }       
        });
    });
```

It works fine in every browser except Firefox. There is [a known bug opened 20(!!) years ago](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53579) that still affects Firefox that cause an infinite loop between focus and blur.
When the code reaches the `$('#nome_field').focus();` line it will focus but then trigger the blur again and run the validation again (infinite loop).

If I decomment this line `$('#nome_field').val('');` then `$('#nome_field').focus();` will never get executed but the input will be cleared. My expectation was that by cleaning the input field I'd fix the bug. Anyway the desired behaviour is to leave what was written by the user for him to fix instead of cleaning the input.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Add something in it to not run it again if it just happened.... boolean or timestamp

Comment: @epascarello this code is supposed to run each time the user blur that field. I cannot determine if the blur happens for user action or for code bug as far as I know.

Comment: Well if it happens x milliseconds after you set focus you know it was not the user....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work around is you can code a safety check that the blur does not happen right after you set the focus.

```
$('#nome_field').blur(function() {
  var tb = $(this);
  if (tb.data("ignore")) {
    return;
  }
  var field_name = tb.val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "check_field_unique.php",
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      field_name: field_name
    },
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(data) {
    if (data.status == 500) {
      //esiste un altro campo con lo stesso nome
      bootbox.alert({
        message: data.message,
        size: 'small',
        backdrop: true,
        callback: function() {
          //$('#nome_field').val('');
          tb.data("ignore", true)
          tb.focus();
          window.setTimeout(function () {
            tb.removeData("ignore");
          }, 100);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: i was working on something similar but was overcomplicating things. This looks simple and robust enough. After 0,1 seconds the lock is released so it will be transparent to the user. Thank you very much!

Comment: checked it but it will not focus the input again. `tb.focus();` seems not to be triggered. How can I debug this?